# Float column of the dataframe, replace comma in place of points

Tags: r, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a column of the dataframe in float64, I need to replace all points with a comma.
In the code I tried to turn the dataframe into a list and use a for loop to use re.sub. But without success.

Thank you for your help

Column: PERCENT

```
46482    0.062500
46483    0.062500
46484    0.062500
46485    0.041667
46486    0.104167
46487    0.104167
46488    0.083333
46489    0.062500
46490    0.041667
46491    0.041667
46492    0.104167
47170    0.230769
Name: PERCENT, Length: 5477, dtype: float64
```

My code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import re

proxy_handler = request.ProxyHandler({})

opener = request.build_opener(proxy_handler)

url = 'XXXXXXXX'

req = opener.open(url)
table = req.read().decode('utf8')

df = pd.read_html(table, header=[0],flavor='bs4')
df = df[0]

df = df.drop(['A', 'B'], axis=1)

#Replace "." to"," in column PERCENT

df = df.T.to_dict().values()
df = list(df)
for i in range(len(df)):
 df = re.sub(r'\.', ',', df[i], flags=re.IGNORECASE)

#ERROR:
#
#Traceback (most recent call last):
#  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
#  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/re.py", line 191, in sub
#    return _compile(pattern, flags).sub(repl, string, count)
#TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

Comment: You need to convert the column to str type first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

`df["PERCENT"] = df["PERCENT"].astype(str).str.replace(".", ",")`